# How can i fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'

Tags: python, file, txt

Hello so i am using python and want to write something to a text file but it doesnt work...
The error part of my code:

```
working_directory = Path(__file__).absolute().parent
profilename1 = Banana
getProductFile = (working_directory + profilename1+".txt")
with open(getProductFile, 'a') as f:
    print('\n'.join(list), file=f)
    print('\n'.join(list1), file=f)
```

when i run it i get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yvesb\OneDrive\Desktop\Script\SATURN.py", line 177, in getLogin
    linkopen()
  File "C:\Users\yvesb\OneDrive\Desktop\Script\SATURN.py", line 204, in linkopen
    getProduct()
  File "C:\Users\yvesb\OneDrive\Desktop\Script\SATURN.py", line 265, in getProduct
    getProductFile = (working_directory + profilename1+".txt")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WindowsPath' and 'str'
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 ways to concat a new path part ot a `pathlib.Path`, the method or the overrided `/`

```
getProductFile = working_directory.joinpath(profilename1 + ".txt")
getProductFile = working_directory / (profilename1 + ".txt")
```

Then you redefine `f` in the `with` block, it should more something like

```
with open(getProductFile, 'a') as f:
    print('\n'.join(list), file=f)
    print('\n'.join(list1), file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path.joinpath` or `os.path.join` instead of string concatenation

```
getProductFile = Path.joinpath(working_directory, profilename1 + ".txt")
getProductFile = os.path.join(working_directory, profilename1 + ".txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine pathes with `/` not `+`:

```
working_directory = Path(__file__).absolute().parent
profilename1 = Banana
product_file = working_directory / (profilename1 + ".txt")
with product_file.open('a') as output:
    print('\n'.join(list), file=output)
    print('\n'.join(list1), file=output)
```